# issue with plotting function in matlab

Tags: plot, matlab-figure

i want to plot this function in matlab :
f(x,y) = (x²+y²)^0.25 * [sin²(50(x²+y²)^0.1) + 1.0];
so heres what i've written :

```
>> x = -100 : 1 : 100; //where x varies
>> y = -100 : 1 : 100; //where y varies
>> A = (power(x, 2)+ power(y, 2));
>> B = 50 * A;
>> C = sin(power(B,0.1));
>> z = (power(A,0.25))*((power(C,2)+1)); 
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.// how can i resolve this error??
```

help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're using matrix multiplication (`*`) when you want element by element multiplication (`.*`). Even with that changed, your code is incomplete since  `x` and `y` are vectors. You probably want to calculate the function for an array of values. This can be done using `meshgrid`. There's more information [here](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/using-matlabs-meshgrid-command-and-array-operators-to-implement-one-and-two-variable-functions.html).

```
x = -100 : 1 : 100;
y = -100 : 1 : 100;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
A = (power(X, 2)+ power(Y, 2));
B = 50 * A;
C = sin(power(B,0.1));
z = (power(A,0.25)).*((power(C,2)+1));
surf(z)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

With some rotating, the figure will look like this:

[image]